# Ph.D. at AEI without a Master's degree

Tags: graduate-admissions, germany

As the title suggests, I just wanted to know if the above is possible (that is, Ph.D. at Albert Einstein Institute without a Master's degree, just with a Bachelor's degree), and if so, are there any problems one would face if they do sign up for such a program?

Answer (score 1):

This is very unlikely. Like many (most?) German institutions a masters is required for admission as they make clear on their web site.

But you can contact them directly. I don't know if they are willing to make exceptions. I suspect that an exception would be made only in an exceptional case.